# how to use jasmine clock (setTimeout) in nested promises when order matters? (jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocking, jasmine

How to use jasmine.clock setTimeout mock inside nested promises? (result: `Error: jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`)

Order is crucial here.

I need to test nested promises that must have setTimeout inside - order matters.
I know that `then` is kind of `process.nextTick` (or `setImmediate`) and it goes beyond current event loop (which is the core problem here) but this `knowledge` does not solve the problem :)

I know that I can put `jasmine.clock().tick()` inside nested promise but this is pointless because I'm testing proper order in some events related lib.

How to test something like this in jasmine? any ideas?

```
it("should run setTimeout mock inside chained promises",(done)=>{

      jasmine.clock().install();

      let realOrder = [];

      let ok1=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve("ok");
      }).then((ok)=>{// this is future - second level

        let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{ // not fired up due to 'then' method
            realOrder.push("1");
            resolve("1");
          },100);
        });
        //jasmine.clock().tick(101); //<- order is crucial here so I can't do that
        return p;

      });

      let ok2=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve("ok");
      }).then((ok)=>{ // second level

        let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{ // not fired up due to 'then' method
            realOrder.push("2");
            resolve("2");
          },50);
        });
        //jasmine.clock().tick(51); //<- order is crucial here so I can't do that
        return p;

      });

      jasmine.clock().tick(151);// we must go outside nested promise - we dont need to run tick inplace because order will change
      Promise.all([ok1,ok2]).then((results)=>{
        expect(results).toEqual(["1","2"]);
        expect(realOrder).toEqual(["2","1"]);
        done();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for those who came with same problem:

[UPDATE]: I created a npm package with that fn https://www.npmjs.com/package/promiseloop

I created a function that will iterate through `then` levels of promise execution and on each level run some function like `jasmine.clock().tick()` so on each level we will have `setTimeout` executed and catched.

```
function promiseLoop(times,iterationFn,finalFn){
  let current=0;
  let p=Promise.resolve("ok");
  function _loop(fn){
    current++;
    if(current<times){
      p=p.then(()=>{
        iterationFn(current);
        _loop(finalFn);
      });
    }else{
      p.then(()=>{
        setImmediate(()=>{
          finalFn();
        });
      });
    }
  }
  _loop(finalFn);
}
```

`times` is a level - how far we want to go through `then` levels?

`iterationFn` is function that will be run on each `then` level

`finalFn` is a final function after last level

---

here is a full example according to question:

```
it("should run setTimeout mock inside chained promises",(done)=>{

      jasmine.clock().install();

      let realOrder = [];

      let ok1=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve("ok");
      }).then((ok)=>{ // second level

        let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{ // not fired up due to 'then' method
            realOrder.push("1");
            resolve("1");
          },100);
        });
        //jasmine.clock().tick(101); //<- order is crucial here so I can't do that
        return p;

      });

      let ok2=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          resolve("ok");
      }).then((ok)=>{ // second level

        let p=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{ // not fired up due to 'then' method
            realOrder.push("2");
            resolve("2");
          },50);
        });
        //jasmine.clock().tick(51); //<- order is crucial here so I can't do that
        return p;

      });

      function iterationTick(){
        jasmine.clock().tick(301); 
        // this will be executed on each promise level in our case second level 
        // that normally would not be catched by 
        // jasmine.clock().tick() because 'then' will be 
        // executed in the future and jasmine.clock().tick() is synchronous 
        // and will not see future setTimeouts
      }

      function finalTick(){
        Promise.all([ok1,ok2]).then((results)=>{
          expect(results).toEqual(["1","2"]);
          expect(realOrder).toEqual(["2","1"]);
          jasmine.clock().uninstall();
          done();
        });
        //jasmine.clock().tick(301);
      }

      promiseLoop(2,iterationTick,finalTick);


  });
```

other example

```
let testNr=0;

new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  resolve("ok");
}).then(()=>{
  // level 1 
  testNr++; // 1 
}).then(()=>{
  // level 2 
  testNr++; // 3 
});

new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  resolve("ok");
}).then(()=>{
  // level 1 
  testNr++; // 2 
}).then(()=>{
  // level 2 
  testNr++; // 4 
});

function each(currentLevel){
  if(currentLevel==1){
    expect(testNr).toEqual(2);
  }else if(currentLevel==2){
    expect(testNr).toEqual(4);
  }
}
function final(){
  expect(testNr).toEqual(4);
  done();
}
promiseLoop(3,each,final);
```